# Discord.js Make channel not sync with category

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I got a problem where I am making a channel and setting the parent of it to a category and it syncs the permissions from the category which I don't want. Is there a way to stop it so I can give it my own permissions?

Here is my code

```js
message.guild.channels
  .create('test', {
    type: 'text',
    parent: '868148689644957726',
  })
  .then((channel) => {
    channel.permissionOverwrites = [
      {
        type: 'member',
        id: message.member.id,
        allow: ['VIEW_CHANNEL'], // is overwritten by the sync of the category
      },
    ];
  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`channel.lockPermissions()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildChannel?scrollTo=lockPermissions) doesn't accept any parameters, it simply locks in the permission overwrites from the parent channel. Even if you pass `false` to it, it just ignores it and still "copies" its parent's permissions.

Also, you can't just update the permissions using [`channel.permissionOverwrites`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildChannel?scrollTo=permissionOverwrites), you need to use the [`channel.overwritePermissions()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildChannel?scrollTo=overwritePermissions) method:

```js
message.guild.channels
  .create('test', {
    type: 'text',
    parent: '868148689644957726',
  })
  .then((channel) => {
    channel.overwritePermissions([
      {
        type: 'member',
        id: message.member.id,
        allow: ['VIEW_CHANNEL'],
      },
    ]);
  });
```

Comment: The channel.lockPermissions() wasn't suppose to be in there i left it in the script i copied by accident. But the function you said made it work thanks for the help.